# Could we have a complete list of StackExchange sites in the footer of all sites?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, footer

For example, at the bottom of a Super User page, there are links to 40 StackExchange sites. But if I visit OnStartups, there are links to 64 sites, and none of them is Super User.

It would be nice to have all sites of StackExchange referenced in the footer of every one of them. Then one could easily check if some subject already has or hasn't a dedicated site.

Comment: You can see all sites at http://stackexchange.com/sites. I don't know why some sites show fewer sites than others though.

Comment: Beta sites have all the other beta sites in the footer. Graduated ones have all the graduated ones.

Comment: And private beta sites only have Area 51 and API/Apps. Cool, never understood that!

Comment: We have 100 sites and counting. Eventually, the "footer" would take up the whole page if we tried to list every site in the footer.

Comment: well, it's not like the footer of a web page limits the height of its content ... ;-)

Comment: @ArneStenström the point Laura makes is that the footer would be too large. Don't read it too verbatim.